# Understanding Calculations in LSTMs

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I’m trying understand LSTMs better:

When we set the LSTM units in Keras or Tensorflow as:

```
model.add(LSTM(256))
```

or

```
lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(256)
```

We are actually setting the dimensions of all 4 Weights (W) in one single LSTM cell, is that right?

eg. Let x have 10 dimensions and batch size = 5 or x.shape=(10, 5) where batch size is the 2nd dimension.
In this forget gate example, we are setting W(f).shape = (256,266) and [h(t-1), x(t)].shape = (266,5),
and the hidden layer h(t-1).shape = (256,5).

[image]

If we use the add notation instead of concatenation and ignoring bias:

```
f(t) = sigmoid(W * x(t) + U * h(t-1))
```

W.shape = (256,10) and U.shape = (256,256)

Is my understanding correct?